# Wintenberger's mystery

Tags: arithmetic-geometry

Fontaine describes in §2 of [this](http://www.springerlink.com/content/6u54ln66l30878jl/) old survey work by Wintenberger and wonders (on p. 97) that the structures found by Wintenberger are a "complete mystery" and no-one knows a "reasonable geometric interpretation". Is that still a mystery?

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you mentioned that the structures in question are canonical $\mathbb{Z}_p$-integral structures on the de Rham cohomology of a smooth proper scheme over $W$, the ring of Witt vectors over a perfect field of characteristic $p$.

Comment: Please read the "how to ask" page, even if you have done so before.

Comment: Thanks Scott, but what should be the mystery? Did you read Winterberger's articles? (I didn't)

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is dead. I'm also unable to find any snapshot saved on the Wayback Machine.